# Adding a SQL Server CE dataset to reportviewer in VS 2012 express C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dataset, sql-server-ce

I am using VS 2012 express coding in C# and have an issue when adding data from a dataset (I use SQL Server CE) to a reportview. My code is this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection con;
    System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds1;

    con = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySalon.Properties.Settings.MySalonConnectionString"].ToString();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_PAYMENTS;";

    try
    {      
        con.Open();
        da = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con)
        ds1 = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds1, "DayRep");

        ReportDataSource datasource;

        datasource = new ReportDataSource("DayRep", ds1.Tables[0]);

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
        con.Close();
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }        
}
```

I can see that datasource has the data but report when pressing the button remains blank (There is no error just blank).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following line of code:

```
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
   "Your_Name_Of_Project.Name_Of_Your_Report.rdlc";
```

It should be if you created your own .rdlc report file so to indicate to reportViewer where to take data from.

Also, where is this line of the code?

```
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Usually, it is added by the studio (if you code using it). It should be in the end of the code, just in the end of your `try` block.  Anyway, it is "mustHave", without it your report really will remain blank.

Also, it seems to me that you should replace this line of code:

```
 ds1 = new DataSet();
```

with this one:

```
 ds1 = new DataSet("myDataSet"); //for exmaple, so to make dataSet have some name
```

and then rewrite this line of code:

```
  datasource = new ReportDataSource("DayRep", ds1.Tables[0]);
```

with next:

```
  dataSource = new ReportDataSource("myDataSet", ds1.Tables[0] as DataTable);
```

**UPDATE**

Well, you have no need to install rdlc teamplate to run and display reports via ReportViewer.

As is told [here](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/), (in examples), you may write it like this

```
// Set Processing Mode

    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    // Set RDL file

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("report1.rdlc", FileMode.Open))
    {
        reportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
    }
```

So, the report will be loaded in the repoerViewer. The main problem here is that I have some .rdlc reports, so I can load them now. To create them without template you can use anther approach, so to create them programmatically - maybe this [article](http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/104659/ShowPost.aspx) can help you. Also, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170239%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) at MSDN.

**UPD2**
You can take a look at the text version of `rdlc` report by using this [link](https://drivenotepad.appspot.com/app?state=%7B%22action%22%3a%22open%22,%22ids%22%3a%5B%220B2fE3q7fXpybQkt1bVZNSkhQeEU%22%5D,%22counter%22:2%7D). But remember that you won't be able to load exactly this `rdlc` into your reportViewer and see the data you want it to. That `.rdlc` is only an example, and every report should be created by the developer of the project. The main reason is that `.rdlc` I have uses DataSet you do not have cause it got data from dataBase you do not have. So, I think the only reason for you to look through this `rdlc` is only getting acquainted. To create `.rdlc` reports successfully, you should use approach I told about before. To get more information, you can try search in google "generate a report definition programmatically" or find some opportunity to create reports in IDE's just like Visual Studio.

Comment: hm-m yes the refreshreport line is in my code at the end of try though i havent created any rdlc file. I just added the reportviewer to a win form. Do i need to do something to create the rdlc file. I think i am gona need the Report Template to create them but how to add this to an express edition?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply!!! I added the code changes to my project. If I understand correct I need to have a valid rdlc file so creating an empty file <name>.rdlc will not give me back anything. Thank you for the links too they are very helpful. If you have any time pls send me an email with a rdlc file. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not have your email cause it's confidential info. You may take a look at the UPD2 section of my answer instead.